# Need help reliably finding asynchronous elements in React with Capybara without using sleep everywhere

Tags: ruby, reactjs, rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Newbie engineer question here, but I've searched and can't find a solution.

Environment: Mac OS, Chrome, Capybara with Selenium Chrome-driver, Ruby with Rspec running the test.

Situation: 
Testing a React app where the user logs in using a username and password, followed by clicking on a sidebar nav link that loads up....followed by other actions.  Capybara continues to fail to find the sidebar nav link to click on.  I believe the sidebar nav is its own React component and loads asynchronously

App & Test Behavior: 
Sometimes Capybara finds the link element, clicks the link and the test passes.  Other times it completely fails to find the element and fails the test.

Solutions I've tried:
Upping the default time for finder methods to continue to search to 15+ seconds(I've never noticed the app take more than 5 seconds on anything)

I only have used finder methods that SHOULD be repeat-searching for the default time for the element to appear (page.find, page.has_css?, etc)before attempting the .click action.  What I have found is that after the login happens, and while the nav is loading, the test just seems to fail with element not found.  The page.find does NOT seem to continue to search for 15 seconds before failing - instead, the login happens, then a second later I get a fail with element not found.

I have tried passing a wait into the find (example: page.find(some element, wait:15).click .   This runs into the same problem as above where it doesn't seem to continue searching for 15 seconds for the element to appear and then click it.

What does seem to work is adding in sleeps before searching for an element (example: login, sleep(5), page.find(something).click).

Unfortunately I'm having this same problem with other elements all over in the app - for example a div may have a bunch of cards in it.  When a new card is added it takes 2-3 seconds to show up in the list (probably due to sending out the card info to the database, and refreshing the cards on the page).  If I try and page.find immediately after adding a card, the test will almost immediately fail with an element not found message.  If I add the card, sleep(3), THEN try page.find, it will find it.

I can't just add sleep all over the place in the app, because its huge and it would slow down the tests immensely. I think I've tried all the typically suggested fixes for asynchronous loading.  Any idea what is going on here and what I can do to fix it

editing to add some requested code.

I'm using capybara 3.2.

We are using a bit of a page object style framework so I"ll try and post the actual test with its methods in bold and helper methods nested in it. 
 Its getting caught in the before action of this particular feature on the final method to click on the sidebar. I'm a little limited on what I can show, but I think this will make sense....

The actual before action:

```
  before do
    **app.launch_app(app.url)**
#  this instantiates an instance of the framework and helper methods and  #  goes to the app url

    **app.login.full_login(app.username('Some User'), app.password)**
#    def full_login(user, pass)
#      enter_email(user)
#        def enter_email(user)
#           return if already_logged_in?
#             def already_logged_in?
#               page.has_css?("a[href*='/me']", wait: false)
#              end
#       fill_field('email', user)
#             def fill_field(field, text)
#               sleep 0.1
#               page.find("input[type=#{field}]").send_keys text
#             end
#       click_button 'Log In'
#             def click_button(text)
#               page.click_on text
#             end
#  end

#      login_using_second_auth(user, pass)
#        def login_using_second_auth(user, pass)
#           page.fill_in 'username', with: user
#           page.fill_in 'password', with: pass
#           click_button 'Sign In'
#          end
#    end

    app.nav.click_sidebar_link('Admin Account', 'Admin')
#      def click_sidebar_link(link, section)
#        sleep(2)
#        page.find('div[class^=app__wrapper] > div > div > div', text: 
#        section)
#        .find('span[class^=nav-item]', text: link).click
#      end 
end
```

Sorry that looks so messy, but I think you guys can make sense of it. 
The test is flaky so after running it a few times I can't get the exact error, but its usually element not found on the span with the text Admin

Comment: Show an example test that fails (and the exact error message you get), so we can see what types of things you're actually calling, also any Capybara config you're using and any RSpec before blocks that would affect the test.

Comment: Also, what version of Capybara are you using?

Comment: According to capybara docs https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends even `click` retries finding element for a period of time before giving up.

Comment: @meta yes, most methods in Capybara will retry which is why The OP needs to post some code to show exactly what they’re doing, and the config they’re using

Comment: updated post with some code

Comment: So here is the actual error:
Failure/Error:
       page.find('div[class^=app__wrapper] > div > div > div', text: section)
           .find('span[class^=nav-item]', text: link).click

     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find visible css "div[class^=app__wrapper] > div > div > div" with text "Admin"